# Loading different versions of the record

Tags: delphi

I have several versions of my data in record stored on the disk:

```
TRec_v1 = record
  Type: UInt32;
  DT1: TDateTime;
end;

TRec_v2 = record
  Type: UInt32;
  DT1: TDateTime;
  DT2: TDateTime;
end;

TRec_v3 = record
  Type: UInt32;
  DT1: TDateTime;
  DT2: TDateTime;
  DT3: TDateTime;
end;
```

Which is the fasted method to read it?

Currently I use this method:

```
  var
    Rec: TRec_v3;
    Rec1: TRec_v1;
    Rec2: TRec_v2;

  FStream := TFileStream.Create(RecPath, fmOpenRead);
  try
    if FStream.Size = SizeOf(TRec_v1) then
      // read to Rec1, assignt to Rec
    else
    if FStream.Size = SizeOf(TRec_v2) then
      // read to Rec2, assigne to Rec
    else
    if FStream.Size = SizeOf(TRec_v3) then
      // read to Rec
  finally
    FStream.Free;
  end;
```

Note: every newer version contain all fields from previous version + new fields

Comment: Does your file contain a single record?

Comment: Yes, one record - one file

Comment: Remy's answer works great with a single record in the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is only one record stored in the file, you can use a `case` statement instead of a series of `if` statements. And since your newer records contain the same fields as your older records, you don't need separate variables, either:

```
var
  Rec: TRec_v3;
  RecSize: Integer;

FStream := TFileStream.Create(RecPath, fmOpenRead);
try
  RecSize := FStream.Size;
  case RecSize of
    SizeOf(TRec_v1),
    SizeOf(TRec_v2),
    SizeOf(TRec_v3):
    begin
      FStream.ReadBuffer(Rec, RecSize);
    end;
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Unsupported record size detected');
  end;
finally
  FStream.Free;
end; 

// use Rec fields depending on RecSize...
```

Alternatively:

```
type
  TRec_v1 = record
    Type: UInt32;
    DT1: TDateTime;
  end;

  TRec_v2 = record
    Type: UInt32;
    DT1: TDateTime;
    DT2: TDateTime;
  end;

  TRec_v3 = record
    Type: UInt32;
    DT1: TDateTime;
    DT2: TDateTime;
    DT3: TDateTime;
  end;

  TRec = record
    case Integer of
      0: (v1: TRec_v1);
      1: (v2: TRec_v2);
      2: (v3: TRec_v3);
  end;

var
  Rec: TRec;
  RecSize: Integer;

FStream := TFileStream.Create(RecPath, fmOpenRead);
try
  RecSize := FStream.Size;
  case RecSize of
    SizeOf(TRec_v1),
    SizeOf(TRec_v2),
    SizeOf(TRec_v3):
    begin
      FStream.ReadBuffer(Rec, RecSize);
    end;
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Unsupported record size detected');
  end;
finally
  FStream.Free;
end; 

// use Rec.v1, Rec.v2, or Rec.v3 depending on RecSize...
```

Answer (score 2):

> Which is the fastest method to read it?

The performance of the code to read the record will be completely dominated by the file access. The majority of the time is spent opening the file, as written in the question.

Using a case statement or if statements is simply a matter of preference and will not lead to observable performance changes.

If this code is buried in a greater whole, then I don't think anyone can advise on the performance without a clear sight of that greater code.

Given the code in the question, the only scope for improving the performance in a measurable way is to evaluate the stream size one time only rather than multiple times.

```
var
  Size: Int64;
....
Size := Stream.Size;
// test Size
```

Even here I doubt you will see a discernible performance impact. However, it is better not to repeat yourself, as a general rule, and this change results in better factored code.

You must measure performance to assess a proposed optimization.

Finally, your entire approach is brittle. If you add an integer to the v3 structure the record size is increased by 8, with padding due to alignment. Add another integer and the size doesn't change, that second integer fitting in the padding. Discriminating based on the type field would be more robust and extendable.

Comment: You asked about performance but you don't seem to be concerned by that. Did you ask the right question.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating, reading and writing a [variant record](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Records), then differentiating between them with a tag:

```
type recordTypeName = record
  fieldList1: type1;
   ...
  fieldListn: typen;
case tag: ordinalType of
  constantList1: (variant1);
   ...
  constantListn: (variantn);
end;
```

Comment: That is changing the structure of the records, though.  Sounds like the OP already has existing files with record data in them.